# AWS EC2 to CloudFront Latency - is it very low?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am considering an application hosted in EC2 that may fetch resources from CloudFront. Assuming the resource is already cached from origin, and assuming the payload is small, what can I expect the fetch latency from within EC2 instance to be? Can I expect 1ms P95, or will it be bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are asking about latency to fetch **from Amazon CloudFront** to an Amazon EC2 instance.

That's interesting! Normally, CloudFront uses an Amazon EC2 instance as the origin, so it is the other way around. But, I can understand that your situation might happen, too.

When Amazon CloudFront is accessed, the request is directly to the "nearest" CloudFront edge location. Which edge is "nearest" is calculated by a combination of latency, number of hops and routing.

Fortunately, **every AWS region has an edge location**. Therefore, the request will go to the edge location in the same region as the Amazon EC2 instance. Thus, **the latency will be extremely low**.

If the content is already cached in that edge location, the response will be very quick. If it is not already cached, CloudFront will need to fetch the resource from the origin before returning the result.

You'll need to measure it to be sure how quick it is, but it should be rather fast.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Definitely will measure it, but good to know it should be fast in theory.